# npm command not found in zsh but found in bash

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, zsh

I installed `npm` with `nvm` and the first time it went all great, now I tried to check npm version on Mac terminal an it shows:

```
% npm --version
zsh: command not found: npm
```

But using VSCode terminal with bash, with same command, shows:

```
npm --version
6.14.12
```

Is there a chance I installed the wrong way `npm` or `nvm`? Or is this a way I can tell Mac terminal to use bash instead of zsh?

Comment: Your PATH's are in sync. Run 'echo $PATH' in both zsh and bash. I'm sure there's something missing.

Comment: bash: `/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

zsh: 
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your PAth's are not the same. This is what is causing your different terminals to not be in sync.

They both have this:

```
 bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin 
 zsh:  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

But only your bash has this:

```
/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin:
```

You should add that to your ZSH PATH. Since you don't have a .zshrc file, do the following in Terminal;

```
echo 'PATH="~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Can you please instruct me on how to add that path to zsh? I'm quite new using MacOS and zsh. I've been reading that I must add `$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin` to my `.zshrc` file but when I do cat to that file it doesn't exist. `cat ~/.zshrc` shows
`cat: /Users/myuser/.zshrc: No such file or directory`. Should I create the file and add this PATH? Works the same way?

Comment: No problem, check above, I edited the post.

Comment: I already execute that command in terminal and `cat ~/.zshrc` shows `PATH="~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin:$PATH"` but still showing command not found even after reseting terminal. Also `echo $PATH` still showing the same path showed in comment above.

Comment: I checked `echo $PATH` again in `zsh` and it now show `~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: Type "where npm" in both zsh and bash, see where it is.

Comment: for `zsh`: `npm not found` and for `bash`: `bash: where: command not found`

Comment: Hey @ErniePC12 I just fixed the problem with your help, I added that PATH to `zshrc` file and run the next command: `source ~/.zshrc` then reset terminal and everything I installed before now I'am able to run it through zsh again. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to this that:
In my case I had node and nvm installed and it was working fine for a long time

`nvm use 16` (my preferred node version) helped

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/320170)